# I want to make this expansion list but cant remove the padding from trailing and increase its height?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove upper and lower padding from expansion tile's trailing so i can fill it with color.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: add design screenshot which you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you need to give like this

Theme(
          data: ThemeData().copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
          child: ListTileTheme(
            dense: true, //removes additional space vertically
            child: ExpansionTile(
              iconColor: ColorResource.Color_CDCDCD,
              collapsedIconColor: ColorResource.Color_CDCDCD,
              title: Text(
                searchData![pos]!.category!,
                style: CustomStyle.size14w600C000000(),
              ),
              children: Conatner(),
            ),
          ),
        );
```